# Java Calling child constructors of same parent class

Tags: java, oop

Any way to simplify this?

```java
switch (student.getYear())
   case 1:
      new FirstYear(student.getId(), student.getName());
      break;
   case 2:
      new SecondYear(student.getId(), student.getName());
      break;
   case 3:
      new ThirdYear(student.getId(), student.getName());
      break;
   default:
      break;
```

where FirstYear, SecondYear, ThirdYear class shares same parent class?

Is there any means in java to pass child class and use its constructor? if they share same constructor structure?

ie.

```java
public static void registerStudent(final Class yearClazz) {
     new yearClazz(student.getId(), student.getName()).save(); //???
}
```

something like this?

Comment: Yes, you can, if you must, do "something like this" using the Reflection framework. But consider this point of design: you already _have_ a class capable of representing a student with Id, name, and year attributes;  do you _really_ need to repackage that data into different classes for the different years?

Comment: Yes, I know this doesn't make sense but this is the Entity Structure of the project I'm working on right now.

Comment: Actually I think I lied. Yes, you can write your `registerStudent` method to look up the needed constructor on `yearClass` and then invoke it, but you _still_ need to select which `Class` to pass to `registerStudent` and that means doing  a `switch` or an `if` cascade.  So, in the end, you really haven't made anything simpler and in fact have increased the amount of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a method reference and functional interfaces. Create an interface (optionally annotated with `@FunctionalInterface`) with a single method that takes a student ID and name, and returns whatever the parent of FirstYear/SecondYear/ThirdYear is. Suppose you call that interface `YearFactory` and the method `makeYear`. Then `FirstYear::new`, `SecondYear::new`, and `ThirdYear::new` will all be objects that implement that interface.

```
switch (student.getYear())
   case 1:
      fac = FirstYear::new;
      break;
   case 2:
      fac = SecondYear::new;
      break;
   case 3:
      fac = ThirdYear::new;
      break;
   default:
      break;
```

```
public static void registerStudent(final YearFactory fac) {
     fac.makeYear(student.getId(), student.getName()).save();
}
```